# Running tests on remote adb server

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, adb

Trying to run gradle tests on remote adb server.

`ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:host:port` and `ADB_DEVICE=emulator-5554` works fine for adb, but not gradle.

Looks like `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT` works for gradle, but I didn't find a way to set adb server host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can tell from Android Studio source code, it does not have support for reading in the host address. It's hard coded:

```
/**
 * Instantiates sSocketAddr with the address of the host's adb process.
 */
private static void initAdbSocketAddr() {
    try {
        sAdbServerPort = getAdbServerPort();
        sHostAddr = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_ADB_HOST);
        sSocketAddr = new InetSocketAddress(sHostAddr, sAdbServerPort);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // localhost should always be known.
    }
}
```

Adb reads *ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS*, so maybe one can extend Android Studio to use this env variable.

A workaround for now is maybe to use iptables to reroute the traffic from 127.0.0.1:5037 to whatever you want, see [answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/823145).